# setTitle to AppCompatDialog not working

Tags: android, dialog, android-appcompat

I am trying to use new `AppCompat 22.1` feature `AppCompatDialog`, but it shows me dialog without title, but I am using method `setTitle`. If I change the `AppCompatDialog` to `Dialog` everything works fine. It's a bug in `AppCompatDialog` ?

Here is my dialog code:

```
final AppCompatDialog dialog = new AppCompatDialog(ctx);
dialog.setTitle(R.string.choose_mode);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_with_list);

ListView listView = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.list_view);

List<ModeItemModel> modesList = new ArrayList<ModeItemModel>();
modesList.add(new ModeItemModel(GUI_MANUAL));
modesList.add(new ModeItemModel(GUI_GPS));
listView.setAdapter(new ModeItemsAdapter(ctx, R.layout.list_item_ico_with_text, modesList));
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
        //Do Action

        dialog.cancel();
    }
});
dialog.setCancelable(true);
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Eddwhis noted in the comments above the `<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>` in the Theme also hides the title of the dialog.
I fixed it by adding a custom AppCompatDialgStyle in which I set `<item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>` to false.

Base theme:

```
<style name="Theme.App.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar,">
   ...
   <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.App.AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
   <item name="dialogTheme">@style/Theme.App.AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
</style>
```

NoActionBar Theme:

```
<style name="Theme.App.NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.App.Base">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

My Dialog style:

```
<style name="Theme.App.AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#f00</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/red</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item> <!-- that's the important bit -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me

> Activity

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        final AppCompatDialog dialog = new AppCompatDialog(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Hello For Dialog");
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_nm);

//        ListView listView = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
//
//        List<ModeItemModel> modesList = new ArrayList<ModeItemModel>();
//        modesList.add(new ModeItemModel(GUI_MANUAL));
//        modesList.add(new ModeItemModel(GUI_GPS));
//        listView.setAdapter(new ModeItemsAdapter(ctx, R.layout.list_item_ico_with_text, modesList));
//        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
//
//            @Override
//            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
//                //Do Action
//
//                dialog.cancel();
//            }
//        });
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();
    }


}
```

> activity_my.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".My">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> dialog layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:background="@android:color/white"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Your message"
        android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

> styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is working? Because, when using `AppCompat v21` you should use `NoActionBar` theme or `<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>` if you want to have toolbar instead of actionBar. And I think this is that is hidding dialog title bar.

Comment: NoActionBar hide the title of dialog also

Comment: But it does not hides title in `AlertDialog`.